# Server Side Includes and GZip?

Tags: iis-6, gzip, ssi

Is it possible to use GZip compression on the ouput of files that have been created using server side includes in IIS 6? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

If IIS can't do this internally, you can do it with [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) techniques.  Basically, the app runs on the server doing the SSI, but outsiders talk to your proxy server which does compression, and gives you a chance to do other clever things, like caching.